# How to pass variable from outside class to class function in php

Tags: php, function, class, variables

i have an php class for to set cron jobs on php, all is working fine but at last step i get stack by passing variable inside class.So my question is how to pass a variable from outside class to inside class function? I tried to set variable before class but still not get any results. My class is:

```
namespace Rumd3x\Scheduler;

use Carbon\Carbon;
use Closure;
use Cron\CronExpression;
use Exception;

class Schedule
{
    const LOCK_FILE = 'scheduler.lock';

    private $action;
    private $name = "Default";

    private $lock = null;
    private $cron = [];

    public function __destruct()
    {
        $this->free();
    }

    public function run()
    {
        $valid_action = ($this->action instanceof Closure);
        if ($this->getLock() && $valid_action) {
            try {
                $cron = $this->makeCron();
                $retorno = $this->eval($cron);
            } catch (Exception $e) {
                $retorno = false;
            } finally {
                $this->free();
                return $retorno;
            }
        }
        return false;
    }

    function eval(CronExpression $cron) {
        if ($cron->isDue()) {
            $now_str = Carbon::now()->format('d/m/Y H:i:s');
            print "[$now_str]: Job {$this->name} Started\n";

            $closure = $this->action;
            $retorno = $closure($cron);

            $now_str = Carbon::now()->format('d/m/Y H:i:s');
            print "[$now_str]: Job {$this->name} Finished OK\n";
        } else {
            $retorno = false;
        }

        return $retorno;
    }

    private function getLock()
    {
        if (!file_exists(self::LOCK_FILE)) {
            file_put_contents(self::LOCK_FILE, '');
        }
        chmod(self::LOCK_FILE, 0777);

        $this->lock = fopen('./' . self::LOCK_FILE, 'r+');

        if (!$this->lock) {
            throw new Exception("Job {$this->name} Failed: Error Opening Lock File\n");
        }

        if (!flock($this->lock, LOCK_EX)) {
            throw new Exception("Job {$this->name} Failed: Error Obtaining Lock on Resource\n");
        }

        return true;
    }

    private function free()
    {
        if ($this->lock && is_resource($this->lock) && get_resource_type($this->lock) !== 'Unknown') {
            flock($this->lock, LOCK_UN);
            fclose($this->lock);
        }
        return $this;
    }

    private function makeCron()
    {
        $parsed = [];
        for ($i = 0; $i <= 4; $i++) {
            $parsed[$i] = isset($this->cron[$i]) ? $this->cron[$i] : '*';
        }
        $expression = implode(' ', $parsed);
        return CronExpression::factory($expression);
    }

    public function isDue()
    {
        return $this->makeCron()->isDue();
    }

    public static function action(Closure $call)
    {
        $instance = new static;
        $instance->action = $call;
        return $instance;
    }

    public function cron(String $expression)
    {
        $this->cron = explode(' ', $expression);
        return $this;
    }

    public function at(String $time)
    {
        try {
            $time = explode(':', $time);
            $this->cron[1] = $time[0]; // Hours
            $this->cron[0] = $time[1]; // Minutes
        } catch (\Exception $e) {
            $this->cron[1] = '*';
            $this->cron[0] = '*';
        } finally {
            return $this;
        }
    }

    public function monthly(Int $day = 1)
    {
        $day = in_array($day, range(1, 31)) ? $day : 1;
        $this->cron[0] = '0';
        $this->cron[1] = '0';
        $this->cron[2] = $day;
        return $this;
    }

    public function weekly(Int $weekday = 0)
    {
        $weekday = in_array($weekday, range(0, 6)) ? $weekday : 0;
        $this->cron = ['0', '0', '*', '*', $weekday];
        return $this;
    }

    public function daily()
    {
        $this->cron = ['0', '0', '*', '*', '*'];
        return $this;
    }

    public function hourly(Int $minute = 0)
    {
        $minute = in_array($minute, range(0, 59)) ? $minute : 1;
        $this->cron = [$minute, '*', '*', '*', '*'];
        return $this;
    }

    public function everyThirtyMinutes()
    {
        $this->cron = ['*/30', '*', '*', '*', '*'];
        return $this;
    }

    public function everyFifteenMinutes()
    {
        $this->cron = ['*/15', '*', '*', '*', '*'];
        return $this;
    }

    public function everyTenMinutes()
    {
        $this->cron = ['*/10', '*', '*', '*', '*'];
        return $this;
    }

    public function everyFiveMinutes()
    {
        $this->cron = ['*/5', '*', '*', '*', '*'];
        return $this;
    }

    public function everyMinute()
    {
        $this->cron = ['*', '*', '*', '*', '*'];
        return $this;
    }

    public function setName(String $name)
    {
        $this->name = $name;
        return $this;
    }
}
```

And i call the class on this way:

```
require_once __DIR__ . './vendor/autoload.php';
use Cron\CronExpression;
use Rumd3x\Scheduler\Schedule;

$getTasks = $database->select("SELECT * FROM crons");
while($row = $database->fetch($getTasks)){
    Schedule::action(function() {
        exec("php -f C:/xampp/".$row['c_file']." 2>&1");
    })->cron(''.$row['c_frequency'].'')->run();
}
```

The problem is that $row['c_file'] and $row['c_frequency'] not working inside class function... how can do this? I tried also to call a function from outside while with variables but still not working.

Thank you!

Comment: Please make sure you only post the specific code that is relevant to the issue/question instead of posting the complete class (which just adds noise to the question). To answer the question, read about `use` in "Example #3" in [the manual about anonymous functions](https://www.php.net/manual/en/functions.anonymous.php)

Comment: Sorry for this, I thought that is more easy to understand...

Comment: In short, this should work: `Schedule::action(function() use ($row) {....})->cron(...)` and it should work. However, there shouldn't be any issues with `$row['c_frequency']` in the posted code though, since it's used outside of the function.

Comment: _Side note:_ You can change `->cron(''.$row['c_frequency'].'')` to `->cron($row['c_frequency'])`. Those quotes are not needed.

Comment: use ($row) is worked!! you saved me mr M. Eriksson :) Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

Change from

```
while($row = $database->fetch($getTasks)){
 Schedule::action(function() {
    exec("php -f C:/xampp/".$row['c_file']." 2>&1");
 })->cron(''.$row['c_frequency'].'')->run();
}
```

To

```
while($row = $database->fetch($getTasks)){
 Schedule::action(function() use($row) { // <-- here used the "use" keyword
    exec("php -f C:/xampp/".$row['c_file']." 2>&1");
 })->cron(''.$row['c_frequency'].'')->run();
}
```